# Rails 4 many to many joint table

Tags: has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to learn many to many relationship, so I have two model Order and Product, I generated with scaffold a join table orders_products with the follow migration:

```
create_table :orders_products do |t|

  t.references :order
  t.references :product
end
```

I have in order model:

```
has_many :orders_products

has_many :products, through: :orders_products

accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders_products
```

in product model:

```
has_many :orders_products

has_many :orders, through: :orders_products

accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders_products
```

in ordersproduct model:

```
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :product
```

in order controller:

```
def new
@order = Order.new
@order.save

@entry = OrdersProduct.create
@entry.product_id = Product.find_by(name: 'default_product').id
@entry.order_id = @order.id    

end


def edit
@order = Order.find(params[:id])

@entries = @order.products

@order.save

end

private   
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:name, orders_products: [:id, :order_id, :product_id])
end
end
```

I am getting undefined method `products  when I am in edit on the line

```
@entries = @order.products
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `has_and_belongs_to_many :products` on Order and `has_and_belongs_to_many :orders` on Product. Wouldn't think `through` is appropriate in this scenario for what you are trying to accomplish. You can also remove the `has_many :orders_products` lines as well.